# Why did we create friend function here.C++

Tags: c++

```
class Accumulator
{
private:
int m_value;
public:
Accumulator() { m_value = 0; } 
void add(int value) { m_value += value; }

// Make the reset() function a friend of this class
friend void reset(Accumulator &accumulator);
};

// reset() is now a friend of the Accumulator class
void reset(Accumulator &accumulator)
 {
// And can access the private data of Accumulator objects
accumulator.m_value = 0;
}

int main()
{
Accumulator acc;
acc.add(5); // add 5 to the accumulator
reset(acc); // reset the accumulator to 0

return 0; 
}
```

I mean what is the use of making  friend function here?I think reset is already a member function and it can easily access private member variable of Class Accumulator.

Comment: Well, `reset` is *not* a member function.

Comment: why so? please could you explain it?

Comment: Because it is declared and defined outside class definition.

Comment: _why did we_ we didn’t

Comment: Do you have a problem indenting the code?

Comment: I'm not sure as to the WHY?  I would not do it that way, unless there was a good reason.  I'm not seeing a good reason.  I would have made reset just a member function of Accumulator instead of a free function, and have called it in main by `acc.reset();`.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a member function, but it would be more OOP and consistent with the `add` function to simply make `reset` a `public` member function.

```
class Accumulator
{
private:
    int m_value;
public:
    Accumulator() { m_value = 0; } 
    void add(int value) { m_value += value; }

    void reset();
};

// reset() is now a member of the Accumulator class
void Accumulator::reset()
{
    m_value = 0;
}

int main()
{
    Accumulator acc;
    acc.add(5); // add 5 to the accumulator
    acc.reset(); // reset the accumulator to 0

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax `reset(acc);` to work `reset` needs to be a free function rather than a member function which would require the syntax `acc.reset()` for invocation.

The free function `void reset(Accumulator &accumulator)` has no relation to `class Accumulator`, so it cannot access the private member `m_value`.
The friend declaration changes the latter and gives the free function the same access than member functions of `Accumulator`.

---

Note that this is particularly useful when overloading operators. E.g. `operator +` should always be declared as free function and usually as friend.

Answer (score 0):

`reset` is not a member function. In fact, this code illustrates syntactic differences between a member function `add` and a non-member function `reset`, with a `friend` designation.

Although both functions can access member variables, `add` does so directly by assigning `m_value`, while `reset` must specify `accumulator` explicitly.

The member/non-member difference shows up at the call site, too, because `add` is called using member syntax, i.e. `acc.add(5)`, while `reset` is called using non-member syntax, i.e. `reset(acc)`.